# C# designing a class to support enumeration

Tags: c#, .net

I've had some trouble trying to work this out, and it's certainly possible that I simply failed to look in the correct places, but I'm having trouble **designing a class that holds a collection of individual properties and also supports easy enumeration of all properties in that class.**

For example:

```
public class CharacterStats
{
    public List<BaseStat> StatList { get; set; }

    private BaseStat Level { get; set; }
    private BaseStat Health { get; set; }
    private BaseStat Damage { get; set; }
    private BaseStat Defense { get; set; }
}

private void InitializeList()
{
    StatList = new List<BaseStat>
    {
        Level,
        Health,
        Damage,
        Defense,
    };
}
```

Ultimately, each of these properties is important in its own right, but there are certain cases where I want to loop through ALL of these properties and perform checks on each of them.

I'm (kind of) familiar with `reflection`, but it feels clunky and unnecessary to iterate over the properties that way. I've currently got this set up to roll the properties into a `List<BaseStat>` and iterate that way, but I'm still not quite sure this is the "correct" implementation.

Some things to note:

- Depending on the usage, I may want to update a reference to a single property (by name), *OR* update the entire collection (presumably through enumeration).
- When updating the entire collection, it will (likely) be with another object of type `CharacterStats` (or something similar) that contains modifiers for some or all of these properties.

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution to represent this class **as a collection** where I can easily update a single value or multiple values as needed.

Is using a `List<T>` or `reflection` the way to go, or is there a better method that I haven't considered? I've done a lot of digging around the interwebs the past few days trying to come up with a solution, but I've either found info that (I believe) is irrelevant, or simply confused myself further.

Objectively, taking into account potential performance issues (I've heard this argument regarding `reflection`), and *especially* ease of use and readability, how should I design this class so that I can work with it as I've described?

Please comment if any further info is needed for clarification.

Comment: Using you code as an example, why not have a `List<BaseStat>`?  Although I don't think it's a very nice solution.

Comment: You could have a property on your class of type IEnumerable<BaseStat> and just yield return all the properties?

Comment: @DarrenYoung Apologies for leaving that code out, but this is what I'm currently doing. This is working, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to represent this data. I've added my List<> code to the example.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, BaseStat>` or a `Dictionary<StatID, BaseStat>` where `StatID` is an enum type. You can then enumerate the dictionary entries or access single properties individually via their name (as a string or enum value)

Comment: So, why do you not start programming? I mean it - read by name is as simple as a method with a switch statement. Given how RARE this requirement is (i.e. few classes will have it), there really is no gain from being "fancy".

Comment: @TomTom I've tried a couple different implementations of this over the past few days and keep running into snags (I'm learning a lot of this as I go) trying to do things like "update a single stat" or "update all of the stats" from different sources. I realize it's a little vague, but the other code using this object is too much to post in the question. I'm trying to back up to the base representation of `stats` to make these additional method calls less clunky. The best I've been able to settle on so far is having a `List` or similar to enumerate all properties or call a single property from.

Comment: It is not really clear what your constraints are here. What is wrong with the solution you have already? Are the property values immutable? If not, is it a problem to reinitialize the list when needed? As commenter @NineBerry already describes, backing the properties with a dictionary would be a good way (and one answerer agrees, copying that suggestion). It is possible to use reflection, if you're concerned about the maintenance cost of keeping the dictionary up-to-date; you can cache property access in `Expression` objects to improve performance. But really, it's just not clear what you want

Comment: @levelonehuman Seriously, I think there is no good solution. The proposed dictionary is ridiculously inefficient in terms of memory use AND runtime compared to properties on a class. I Would "just live with ugly code" for such an edge case. You will not write this hundreds of times.

Comment: @TomTom care to elaborate on inefficiency, especially when it comes to 4 elements?

Comment: @Tom: _"proposed dictionary is ridiculously inefficient"_ -- I'm hard-pressed to see how it's even "inefficient", never mind "ridiculously inefficient". In any real-world program, it's unlikely one would even be able to measure the execution difference in performance between the two. A dictionary will use slightly more memory, but not anywhere close to enough extra for it to have any impact on the program's performance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Really, this started off as me wondering how it would be possible to represent a class as a list so that I could do something like `CharacterStats.ForEach(...);`, but it became clear pretty quickly that what I'm doing now is at least close to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also look into the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class which is made with dynamic properties in mind, and also allows for enumeration of these (through the implementation of the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface.

---

Note that your sample code has a big issue: it adds the properties early to the list (or dictionary if you were to use that), but these are not kept in sync with changes to the real object properties. If you want to keep a hand-made solution which is about as generic as the one you have made, I'd rather do this:

```
public class CharacterStats
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseStat> GetStats() {
        yield return Level;
        yield return Health;
        yield return Damage;
        yield return Defense;
    }

    public BaseStat Level { get; set; }
    public BaseStat Health { get; set; }
    public BaseStat Damage { get; set; }
    public BaseStat Defense { get; set; }
}
```

The enumeration here does not "communicate" the property type, so that should be covered either by the concrete type (e.g. by having classes like LevelStat, HealthStat etc.) or by returning an enumeration of KeyValuePair with a name or enum as key.

Comment: Your note about the issue with my code: I should note first that I'm still learning, but I had the impression that I was just adding references of these properties (since they're objects) to the list; is this not the case? It's also worth noting that I did not post the code where I'm initializing these properties. Could you elaborate for me on the issue with my implementation and how I might be able to fix it? I like the idea of the `IEnumerable`; I may end up trying this next. Thanks!

Comment: @levelonehuman In your `InitializeList` method you copy the reference stored in the property to your list - not a reference to the property itself. Therefore your list is a snapshot of what the properties were when `InitializeList` ran, and further changes to the properties (or items in the list) do not have any effect on the other. That's why I'm suggesting the enumeration code; it will execute each time you run the enumeration, thereby giving out the references stored in the properties at the time the enumeration runs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I hadn't gotten far enough with my testing code yet to see this - thank you for the info.

Comment: @levelonehuman Great - thanks for the feedback, and happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary<String,BaseStat>`.
You can iterate `dic.Keys` or access `dic["Level"]`.

Bonus points if you actually use an `enum` as key type, to prevent typos.

Comment: You could iterate over `dic.Values` to access all the values without looking up the keys.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with copying an answer from comments, but you should at least acknowledge [the original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183703/c-sharp-designing-a-class-to-support-enumeration#comment60002919_36183703).

Comment: @PeterDuniho: i wrote my answer at the same time as thiw comment was written.